# how to disable "Retype new password" when changing password in RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, passwd

Is there a configuration setting in RHEL/CentOS thru which `Retype new password` can be disabled while changing user password?

In shell we can use `echo 'username:newpassword' | chpasswd`

I have to set it to be changed non-interactively thru an application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the double prompt from `passwd`. It's there to safeguard against mistyping. If it's really that much of a problem then you have a number of choices

1. If your script runs as `root` you can use `chpasswd`
2. You can get the source for `passwd`, modify it and build your own one-shot version (ideally alongside the existing tool rather then replacing it)
3. You can write your own tool, much like `chpasswd`
4. You can rethink how your application works

At least three of these suggestions have knock-on security implications that you would need to consider carefully. Presumably you wouldn't want any user being able to change any other user's password

Comment: Thanks @roaima for confirming this. I have a third party application which requires this capability. Cheers.